# Are the two cores of rMPB enough?

Tags: macbook-pro, performance, processor

I am thinking of purchasing a 13" rMBP. It has two cores. My question is, are two cores enough ? there are other laptops with 4 cores at much cheaper rates available. How does apple seem to pull it off with only 2 cores ? will the performance of a rMPB and a quad core(similar specs) have the same performance?

and, is it worth buying the 2 cores ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you're going to use it.

If your daily MacBook usage only consists of stuff like websites browsing, watching movies on VLC and creating a Word or Excel document from time to time, then, I would say, 2 cores are surely enough.

But if you're using software that requires more resources like audio/video processing (Adobe products, for example), graphic excessive games, etc. then go for 4 cores.

Comment: Using 'graphic excessive games' i would advice to go with a dedicated GPU...